# Thevenin equivalent and op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, thevenin

I have some problems obtaining the thevenin equivalent with op amp. The next example is in Fundamentals of electric circuits of Sadiku. Can you help me get thevenin equivalent from the example?

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/savf29f28q5andq/example.jpeg]

Comment: So what exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Obtaining Rthev, what I have to do with the op amp?

Comment: I need thevenin equivalent :)

Comment: Sorry, I change it hehe

Comment: It is important to realize that the opamp output can be considered as an ideal voltage source, it controlled by  \$v_i\$, but that is of little difference for Thévenin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First deal with the op amp. It has a gain = -Rf/R1 so that the voltage feeding into R2 is -vi * Rf/R1.Note that the op amp will invert the signal voltage. The output resistance is taken as zero for a perfect op amp.

[image]

C is in parallel with R3. This needs to be reduced to a single impedance.

[image]
[image]

And at that point you should be able to easily reduce the circuit to a Thevanin equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Just like any other circuit, to get the Thevenin equivalent, you need to know two things:

- The open-circuit output voltage
- The short-circuit current

To get the open circuit voltage you need to analyze two things:

- The inverting amplifier circuit formed by the op-amp, Rf, and R1
- The voltage divider circuit formed by R2 and the parallel combination of R3 and C

To get the short-circuit output current, you just need to look at the output of the inverting amplifier subcircuit and R2.

Since there's a capacitor included in the circuit, you'll need to write a formula for each of these values as a function of frequency.

The Thevenin equivalent supply voltage is the same as the open-circuit output voltage.

If the open-circuit voltage is *V<sub>o</sub>* and the short-circuit output current is *I<sub>s</sub>*, then the Thevenin equivalent impedance is *V<sub>o</sub>* / *I<sub>s</sub>*.